# Show changelog when chrome extension is updated

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to show a changelog to the user when a chrome extension is updated. I read the documentation about `onInstalled` and `onUpdated` but I'm not sure how to proceed, do I need to create a page inside the extension and load it using these two events or there is another way to chieve this?

Comment: `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(details=>{ if (details.reason == 'update') chrome.tabs.create({url:'mychangelog.html'});});`

Comment: @IvánNokonoko thanks for the suggestion.